# Complement of a confidence set: standard name?

Tags: confidence-interval, terminology

In the context of statistical inference, is there a standard name for the complement of a confidence set?

For example, suppose $X$ captures the observed data, $\theta$ the parameter of interest, $\Theta$ the universe of $\theta$. Suppose also we have construct $I(X)\subset\Theta$ as a confidence set for $\theta$. What is the name of $\Theta\backslash I(X)$?

Comment: I don't think this has a particular name - you would just describe it as the complement of the confidence set.